# Using laravel array form checkbox in edit mode

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

This is example form code:

```
{{Form::checkbox('selection[]', '1')}}
{{Form::checkbox('selection[]', '2')}}
{{Form::checkbox('selection[]', '3')}}
{{Form::checkbox('selection[]', '4')}}
```

This is example code for saving:

```
$selection = json_encode(Input::get('selection'));
```

It will be then save into MySQL table in 'selection' column.

So now, how can I retrieve the data into the form edit mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$selections = json_decode($selectionFieldFromDB); // pass it to the view

// then just:
@foreach (range(1,4) as $i)
 {{ Form::checkbox('selection[]', $i, in_array($i, $selections)) }}
@endforeach
```

Mind that if you have an attribute on your model `selection`, then Laravel will ignore `in_array()` part, since it first checks the values on the bound object.

So if you want it to work like I suggested, don't use `selection` name for the checkboxes if that's the name of your model attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I found a problem that all `selection[]` checkbox will be checked when `selection` field in the database table got value. How can I overcome that?

Comment: You're wrong, only those from db will be selected, so show your code.

Comment: I believe I'm not wrong. You may try with it. Even with non-array checkbox, the selection of the checkbox is depending on database. No matter what I set it to be checked or not, it will be ignored on edit mode.

Comment: I've tried it, believe me, it works. So show your code, otherwise I can't help you. Unless you don't want it to be dependant on the DB entries, which I can't imagine.

Comment: Hi, here is my code on another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800265/unable-to-set-laravel-checkbox-selected-in-edit-mode. Hope you can help to see the problem. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: I wasn't trying to be different in editing. I was trying with the array checkboxes, and I face the problem. So that was my clean experiment example of the problem. When it is array checkbox, the db value will be something like `['1','4','5']`. Then all checkboxes will be selected no matter what.

Comment: The thing is, it depends on how you store these values on your bound model AND how you reference it in the `Form::checkbox`. Check my edit in a moment. And by the way this question is not about form model binding ;)