# Unable to set Laravel checkbox selected in edit mode

Tags: php, checkbox, laravel-4

I am having trouble to set the laravel checkbox selected in edit mode. So, I do the testing with clean install of latest version of laravel and created a MySQL table named "checkbox" which contains 2 columns. One is `id` and the other one is `mycheckbox`.

Here is my code:

```
Route::get('/checkbox', function(){
    $data = DB::table('checkbox')->where('id', '1')->first();
    var_dump($data);
    echo Form::model($data);
    echo Form::checkbox('mycheckbox', '1',true);
    echo Form::close();
});
```

I found out that no matter what I set the checkbox to be checked or not on the checkbox helper, it will always follow the data from database.

How can I solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: This is how form model binding works and definitely it is expected behaviour. Why on earth you would like it to be different to what you you in your DB, when editing entries? Don't use `Form::checkbox` if you don't want it.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk What I mean is when using `Form::text` or any other helper, it works. Custom value will overwrite the database value, but not on checkbox & radio. Because of this, I am having issue with `Form::checkbox('mycheckbox[]', '1',true)`.

Comment: Like I said, this is expected behaviour. Why you don't want it to be value from the db?

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk For example, the array checkbox like from our other post discussion. In such case, all array checkboxes will be checked.

Comment: You're not answering my question - why do you want it to be different to what you have in the db, when you are editing data??

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk That is just my clean working experiment on the problem. Will continue the discussion with you on Array post.